# Test Android Jetpack Navigation findNavController in onCreate method

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-jetpack-navigation

According to the latest changes in Android Jetpack Navigation component *NavHostFragment* creates instance of NavController in his *onCreate()* method before any child fragment is recreated. Consequently it allows to call *findNavController()* even in our own fragment's *onCreate()* method.

Here is the official example of testing navigation call(https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing):

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TitleScreenTest {

    @Test
    fun testNavigationToInGameScreen() {
        // Create a TestNavHostController
        val navController = TestNavHostController(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())

        // Create a graphical FragmentScenario for the TitleScreen
        val titleScenario = launchFragmentInContainer<TitleScreen>()

        titleScenario.onFragment { fragment ->
            // Set the graph on the TestNavHostController
            navController.setGraph(R.navigation.trivia)

            // Make the NavController available via the findNavController() APIs
            Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
        }

        // Verify that performing a click changes the NavController’s state
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.play_btn)).perform(ViewActions.click())
        assertThat(navController.currentDestination?.id).isEqualTo(R.id.in_game)
    }
}
```

In this example *NavController* object is set only when the fragment's view is already available.

Is there any pure standard way to test the navigation call if we have it during fragment's *onCreate()* method?

e.g.

```
class TitleScreen : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_title_screen) {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_title_screen_to_in_game)
    }
}
```